# SNMP for detecting server data

Tags: php, snmp

**Greetings fellow coders and brainz..**

working on a project where I need to implement some retreival of systemdata (OS, CPU, Memory aso.) via SNMP.

I googled for classes to help, for scripts to assist. And I just found some basics for Cisco routers/switches. None for servers and the like.

Discovered that the snmp-get-data part isnt the hard part. It is the "*Get the specifics"* out.

Is there anyone out there that has any idea, pointers or anything else that I might be able to use?

Comment: I'm guessing, from the tag, that you need to do this in PHP? Or are you looking for any script at all that can help?

Comment: that is correct. php.